# Using $.data in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am experiencing problems (only on Firefox) using jquery data.

In my case, the debugger says that the div I'm trying to use isn't defined.

Is there anything I should read or be aware about?

Here is a jsFiddle: (Sorry for the mess, but i've prepared this just for showing)

http://jsfiddle.net/Rn8rh/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data = {
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorDesc": "No Error",
    "tabelaUsers": [{
      "id": "537",
      "nome": "A3     a",
      "perfil": "Gestor Plataforma, Professor",
      "pendente": "0",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "21",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "52",
      "nome": "Afonso Sancho",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "0",
      "numEscola": "6",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "588",
      "nome": "Aluno1",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "27",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "619",
      "nome": "Aluno231 - editado 2x",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "38",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "543",
      "nome": "Alvo",
      "perfil": "Professor, Gestor Plataforma",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "23",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "585",
      "nome": "Ambr\u00f3sio II",
      "perfil": "Professor, Gestor Plataforma",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "25",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "686",
      "nome": "Barney",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "92",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "527",
      "nome": "Billy G",
      "perfil": "Professor, Gestor Plataforma",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "13",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "51",
      "nome": "Claudio Fernandes",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "0",
      "activo": "0",
      "numEscola": "5",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "703",
      "nome": "Coiso",
      "perfil": "Gestor Plataforma, Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "109",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "636",
      "nome": "Cordeiro",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "52",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "530",
      "nome": "Durval Moreirinhas",
      "perfil": "Gestor Plataforma, Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "16",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "533",
      "nome": "George McFly1",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "19",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "653",
      "nome": "Grovsny Vladimir ",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "69",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "76",
      "nome": "Henrique Peixoto",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "0",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "9",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "611",
      "nome": "JB teste",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "32",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "612",
      "nome": "Joaquim Barradas",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "33",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "613",
      "nome": "Joaquim Barradas - Aluno 2",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "34",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "614",
      "nome": "Joaquim Barradas - Professor 1",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "35",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "633",
      "nome": "jose 11",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "49",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "53",
      "nome": "Jos\u00e9 Nunes",
      "perfil": "Professor, Gestor Plataforma",
      "pendente": "0",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "7",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "632",
      "nome": "Jos\u00e9 Nunes1",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "48",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "656",
      "nome": "Josegefefefe",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "72",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "676",
      "nome": "Jos\u00e9s",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "87",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "538",
      "nome": "Laercio",
      "perfil": "Professor, Gestor Plataforma",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "22",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "544",
      "nome": "La\u00e9rcio Fernandes",
      "perfil": "Professor, Gestor Plataforma",
      "pendente": "0",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "24",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "77",
      "nome": "Lu\u00eds Louren\u00e7o",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "0",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "10",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "687",
      "nome": "Magica de Spell",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "93",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "689",
      "nome": "Maria Alice",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "95",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "688",
      "nome": "Mister T",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "94",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "654",
      "nome": "OAOAOOAOOOA",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "70",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "690",
      "nome": "Olga AAA",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "96",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "705",
      "nome": "Oscar Burante",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "111",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "648",
      "nome": "Outro",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "64",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "649",
      "nome": "outro1",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "65",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "54",
      "nome": "Paulo Peixoto",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "0",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "8",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "642",
      "nome": "Professor",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "58",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "668",
      "nome": "professor",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "84",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "644",
      "nome": "Professor 1234",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "60",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "645",
      "nome": "Professor 32322",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "61",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "528",
      "nome": "Professor Ludovico",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "0",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "14",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "89",
      "nome": "Professor Pardal",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "0",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "11",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "643",
      "nome": "Professor123",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "59",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "669",
      "nome": "professor2",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "85",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "641",
      "nome": "sada123",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "57",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "667",
      "nome": "sadadas",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "83",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "628",
      "nome": "sadasdasdas",
      "perfil": "Gestor Plataforma, Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "45",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "531",
      "nome": "S\u00e9rgio Azevedo",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "17",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "605",
      "nome": "Teste HC Aluno",
      "perfil": "Gestor Plataforma, Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "28",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "662",
      "nome": "Usu\u00e1rio com email",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "78",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "657",
      "nome": "Usu\u00e1rio1",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "73",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "650",
      "nome": "Usu\u00e1rio1",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "66",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "658",
      "nome": "Usu\u00e1rio2",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "74",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "659",
      "nome": "Usu\u00e1rio3",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "75",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "526",
      "nome": "utilizadoor A",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "0",
      "numEscola": "12",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "50",
      "nome": "Utilizador Coordenador Ciclo, Professor",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "4",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "685",
      "nome": "Utilizador Pr\u00e9-pendente",
      "perfil": "Aluno",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "91",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "46",
      "nome": "Utilizador professor",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "1",
      "estado": "1"
    }, {
      "id": "47",
      "nome": "Utilizador professor,  Coordenador Ciclo",
      "perfil": "Professor",
      "pendente": "1",
      "activo": "1",
      "numEscola": "2",
      "estado": "1"
    }]
  };


  for (var i in data.tabelaUsers) {
    $('#listUsersEscola').append("<div class='userItem userLine' id='" + data.tabelaUsers[i].id + "'><div style='line-height: 40px; width: 75px; float: left; text-align: center;'>" + data.tabelaUsers[i].numEscola + "</div><div class='item_usuario' id='" + data.tabelaUsers[i].id + "' style='cursor: pointer; line-height: 40px; width: 255px; float: left; padding-left: 30px; margin-right: 20px;' >" + data.tabelaUsers[i].nome + "</div><div style='float: left; height: 40px; display: inline-block; width: 150px; line-height: 40px; font-size: 11px;'>" + data.tabelaUsers[i].perfil + "</div><div id='statusFor" + data.tabelaUsers[i].id + "' style='width: 146px; float: left; display:inline-block; position: relative; left: 16px;'></div><div style='float: right; display: inline; position: relative; left: 0px;'><a href='#confirmaApagarUsuario' id='apagarUsuario" + data.tabelaUsers[i].id + "' title='' onclick='$.data(listUsersEscola, \"idU\", \"" + data.tabelaUsers[i].id + "\");' class='inline'><img class='imgDeleteUsuario' src='http://trac.balancer.ru/bors-core/export/93853ebb39eda84d0e16503a15601d5c31bad8d9/shared/i16/delete.png' alt=''></a></div></div><div class='clear'></div>");
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="listUsersEscola" style="width: 100%;overflow: hidden; "></div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you click on the image firebug prints the error

Comment: Can you post your code? I have never had any problems using jquery data in firefox.

Comment: Please share your code with us (edit it into your question). It's quite hard to tell the problem without seeing it. The best solution would be that you set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I'm looking over the jsFiddle, and I'm not sure what I'm looking for.  What image are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry .. the 'X' image. I've updated the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

I was trying

> $.data(divId, 'nameOfVar'), then $.data($('#divId'), 'nameOfVar')

I've changed to

`$.data(document.getElementById(divId), 'nameOfVar')` and now it works